# Simple HTML DOM only returns partial html of website

Tags: php, web-scraping

I had a big PHP script written out to scrape images from this site: "http://www.mcso.us/paid/", but when it didn't work I butchered my code to simply echo the whole page.

I found that the table with the image links I want doesn't show up. I believe it's because the remote site uses ASP to generate the table. Is there a way around this? Am I wrong? Please help.

```
<?php
include("simple_html_dom.php");
set_time_limit(0);

$baseURL = "http://www.mcso.us/paid/";
$html = file_get_html($baseURL);
echo $html;
?>
```

Comment: You are correct, the page is using ajax and asp to generate the content. You will have to use curl or something on the page it's getting the information from and parse that instead.

Answer (score 0):

There's no obvious reason why them using ASP would cause this, have you tried navigating the page with JavaScript turned off? It's a more likely scenario that the tables are generated through JS.

Answer (score 0):

Do note that the search results are retrieved through ajax ( page http://www.mcso.us/paid/default.aspx ) by making a POST request, you can use cURL http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php , use chrome right-click-->inspect element---> network and make a search you will see all the info there (post variables etc ...)